# During Jitsi meet screen share from android capture sound of audio/video files playing in mobile

Tags: android, jitsi, screensharing, jitsi-meet, video-conferencing

We can share the screen from android devices during a Jitsi meet. but If we are playing a video on screen, the sound/audio of the video is not shared with the participants. How can I implement this?